# Бельмес и его значение

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Значение слова *бельмес* в переводе "не знает, не понимает". В связи с этим возникает вопрос. Если значение слов являются синонимами, то их можно применять как аналоги одного и того же свойства. Но тогда не понятно, как объяснить применение слова на следующих примерах: *Я не знаю английского(языка) = я не понимаю английского(языка)* — это ясно для понимания, слух не режет. 
Но если мы скажем: *Я не знаю этого человека (Ивана Сергеевича),* что не равно *Я не понимаю этого человека (Ивана Сергеевича).* Это уже совершенно иной смысл , совершенно противоположный первому примеру. Как же так, ведь это слово (фраза) должно работать аналогичным образом?

Comment: а при чем тут бельмес?

Comment: Да, смысл вопроса несколько размыт...

Comment: Я  тоже  не  бельмес !

Answer (score 2):

> Ни бельмеса не смыслить (не понимать). "Бильмез" по-татарски (и на
>   многих других тюркских языках) означает: невежда, ничего не знающий
>   человек (точнее, "бильмез" - "он не знает").
>
> Общаясь с татарами (и другими тюрками), русские часто слышали от них
>   слово "бильмез", когда выяснялось чье-нибудь взаимное непонимание.
>   Понятно, как в конце концов, сложилась и эта полурусская,
>   полутатарская поговорка.

Даль так объясняет:
"балбес, дурень, болван, ничего не смыслящий. Более употреб. в поговорке: *Он ни бельмеса не смыслит, ни аза в глаза. Не смыслит ни бельмеса, а суется бесом".*

[Источник](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/3017350)

Comment: Спасибо. Поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Перевод слов с одного языка на другой часто заставляет использовать не только синонимы, но и, казалось бы, далекие по значению слова. Одним словом бывает трудно передать все оттенки значений в исходном языке.

В данном случае "понимать" и "знать" хотя бы в чем-то синонимичны. Это не значит, что можно их запросто менять местами в разных предложениях.

Answer (score 0):

1. В русском языке у слова "бельмес" нет собственного значения.
   Этимологический словарь русского языка Макса Фасмера:

> бельме́с **только в выражении** ни бельме́са не понима́ет. [Выделил я]

Анализ употребления указывает, что бельмес выполняет роль слова "ничего".

2. Разговор о синонимии глаголов знать и понимать возник только по тому, что слово балбес  переводится разными русскими словами. Странная, ПМСМ, логика, по ней получается что бак и водоём это синонимы. Они оба являются переводами слова "Tank".
3. Знать и понимать любой язык (кроме языка людоедки Эллочки) это разные понятия, которые более различны, чем схожи.  Например, русский язык знают практически все граждане РФ, а понимают не более 20%. В Интернете это на любых форумах и чатах, в любых соцсетях явно видно.